# Firefox - Dialogue Box Settings

Tags: firefox, popups, about-config

I erroneously set Firefox to never **allow dialogue windows for a certain website**. Now I really need to see those dialogues and I can't find an option to reset my choice. Preferably I would prefer to find the right entry in the `about:` pages or maybe delete the relevant file in the installation folder.

Comment: How did you "set Firefox to never allow dialogue windows for a certain website"? In what FF version, current FF version and OS?

Comment: The dialogue for a certain operation came with a checkbox to not show the message anymore. I thought the operation would perform anyways, so I madked it.